# How do you customize open link in new window shortcut key in macOS Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, shortcut

I'm trying to switch from Chrome to Safari and want the same keyboard shortcuts for new tabs and windows.

How do I change Safari so when I hold shift and left-click a link it opens the link in a new Safari window?

The only options for changing shortcuts are in the Safari Preferences Tabs panel.

I looked at the OS-level shortcuts option, but that seems to require an action from the Application menus. I need the right-click context menu action.

Comment: I think what you're asking is not as easy as just changing some existing settings, in the **UI** or the _command line_ in **Terminal** if even there is a way. -- Is there some reason you cannot just get used to **⌥⌘-Click** on a _link_ to open in a new window and **⌘-Click** on a _link_ to open in a new tab in **Safari**?

Comment: I can get used to a lot, however, I regularly must build web software and need to move between Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Both Chrome and Firefox use the same window / tab hotkey convention.

I'm open to using something like Automator, or even Keyboard Maestro. I do not understand why these common task hotkeys are not customizable in the first place.